# Retrieve application config from secure location during task start

Tags: amazon-s3, docker, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I want to make sure I'm not storing sensitive keys and credentials in source or in docker images. Specifically I'd like to store my MySQL RDS application credentials and copy them when the container/task starts. The documentation provides an example of [retrieving the ecs.config file from s3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html#ecs-config-s3) and I'd like to do something similar.

I'm using the Amazon ECS optimized AMI with an auto scaling group that registers with my ECS cluster. I'm using the [ghost docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ghost/) without any customization. Is there a way to configure what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a volume on the host and map it to the container with Read only privileges.
Please refer to the following documentation for configuring ECS volume for an ECS task.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html

Even though the container does not have the config at build time, it will read the configs as if they are available in its own file system.

There are many ways to secure the config on the host OS.
In my past projects, I have achieved the same by disabling ssh into the host and injecting the config at boot-up using cloud-init.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing. Just forgot to put an answer so I'll give you credit.